# I view three image in single row how to show remining image in next row

Tags: android, image

Hello I use some images and view the three image in single row it view correctly.but exactly 4,8,12,....image only view .suppose I have 5 or 6 image means it show 4 image only remaining  image not show.I use this code.

```
if(i%4==0){
                     if(myrow!=null){
                         table.addView(myrow);
                     }else{

                     }
                myrow=new LinearLayout(Engagement_ViewTable.this);
                myrow.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                myrow.addView(row);     
                }

                 else{
                    myrow.addView(row);         
                }
```

Now I get result in this way
if 5 image means
 1   2    3  4

if 6 image means
 1   2    3 4
If 8 image means
 1    2    3   4
 5    6    7   8
  like wise

But I want If 5 image means
 1   2   3  4
 5
 if 6 image means
 1    2   3   4
 5    6
if 8 image means
 1   2   3   5
 5   6   7   8
thanks with out using grid view

Comment: Better way is to use GridView.

Comment: What is your requirement? Is it to show 3 images in a table row..Beneath that comes next table row with 3 images and so on?

Answer (score 1):

I think a GridLayout is what you're looking for. Learn about it here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Edit: In case you wish to have different number of columns in landscape mode and portrait mode, along with the options to sync grid position across orientation changes and support for headers & footers, check out Etsy's **AndroidStaggeredGrid** library:

https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid